# Container with fast inserts and index?

Tags: c++, vector, avl-tree

I am looking for a C++ container class that is indexed like an `std::vector`, but has fast insertions, deletions and indexing.  For example, a `vector` interface implemented with an underlying balancing tree would have O(logN) insertions/deletions and O(logN) indexing as well.

To be clear: I am not looking for `std::map<int, T>`.  Inserting an element at index `N` should increment indices of all subsequent elements in the array which would not be the case with `std::map<int, T>`.

I have found [AVL Array](http://avl-array.sourceforge.net/) which does exactly what I am looking for.  It has the right interface, but I would like to see if there are other options.

Do you know any other (production-quality) implementations?  Maybe something more popular (does boost have something of the sort?).  Something with a smaller memory footprint? (A node holding a pointer in the AVL Array is 64 bytes on my machine.)

Comment: can you elaborate on why you require the random access?

Comment: This appears to be off-topic - looking for software/library recommendations.

Comment: I don't think there's a simpler (in terms of data structure) thing that does what you want, so it requires 2 ptrs for next/prev and 3 ptrs for parent/left/right plus the original pointer. In total, 6 pointers = 48 bytes for 64 bit environments. That's the least you can achieve in terms of memory footprint (I think).

Comment: if you can get rid of your random access requirement, hashtables might do the trick - also if your input size is orders less than a million, shifting an array is actually very cheap - assuming you don't do too many re-allocations.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the rank variable on each node.

Answer (score 1):

Thought about using SkipLists yet? Basically it is a linked list, with multiple levels of shortcuts added on top that are organised as a tree. No shuffling of nodes, just a few pointer updates. The shortcuts allow you to iterate much faster across your list. One of my favorites.

http://openmymind.net/Building-A-Skiplist/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list